# How to use matplotlib in Plone

Tags: matplotlib, plone

I am using Plone 4.3 with matplotlib. I have the plot window but I want to render the plot window in a page template. Some folks suggested I use HTML5 `canvas` to render the plot window in a template page. But I am unable to grasp that concept. So anyone can help me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a browser view, set the header type, and return the image data e.g.

```
from zope.publisher.browser import BrowserPage


class PloneMatPlotLib(BrowserPage):
    """
    """

    def __call__(self):

        import cStringIO
        from matplotlib.figure import Figure
        from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg

        x, y = 4, 4

        fig = Figure(figsize=[x, y])
        ax = fig.add_axes([.1, .1, .8, .8])
        ax.scatter([1, 2], [3, 4])
        canvas = FigureCanvasAgg(fig)

        # write image data to a string buffer and get the PNG image bytes
        buf = cStringIO.StringIO()
        canvas.print_png(buf)
        data = buf.getvalue()

        # write image bytes back to the browser
        self.request.response.setHeader("Content-type", "image/png")
        return data
```

You can then call this view TTW (through the web) to get the image e.g. `http://localhost:8080/Plone/@@plone_matplotlib`. Or in a page template e.g.:

```
<div metal:use-macro="here/main_template/macros/master">
    <div metal:fill-slot="main">
       <img tal:attributes="src python:context.absolute_url() + '/@@plone_matplotlib'">
    </div>
</div>
```

More here:

- https://github.com/aclark4life/plone_matplotlib

Comment: No problem! Hope it helps

Comment: Same way you draw a line on an image which is not in a browser page, I imagine

Comment: if i get mouse point value from browser page using jquery  means  that it is  possible way to draw line . but i can't run any JavaScript script file inside the pt page

Comment: i can call this view TTW (through the web) to get the image e.g. http://localhost:8080/Plone/@@plone_matplotlib. but i can't display image using  page template .

Comment: Why not? You should be able to :-)