# Can zope.publisher.browser.BrowserView be used in Plone?

Tags: plone, zope, zope3

Given that `Products.Five` is an integration layer to make the Zope Component Architecture (ZCA) usable in Plone:

- **Is it possible to use zope.publisher.browser in Plone or do I have to use Products.Five.browser to import BrowserView?**

The former produces a traceback:

`2015-06-04 14:47:02 ERROR Zope.SiteErrorLog 1433443622.720.549321919726 http://localhost:8080/Plone/@@hello
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 138, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 48, in call_object
  Module zope.publisher.browser, line 968, in __call__
NotImplementedError: Subclasses should override __call__ to provide a response body`

Whereas the latter "just works"

Comment: Who is down voting this and why? Please don't down vote without including a constructive comment. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `Products.Five.browser.BrowserView` because it is in charge of plugging the view in Acquisition, hence (among others) in Zope 2 security infrastructure.

It inherits from `AcquisitionBBB`.

Zope 2 security relies on acquisition to configure permissions only at root of content trees.

Comment: Confusingly, I am using zope.publisher.browser.BrowserPage here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23779925/185820. That's confusing on two levels: 1.) What's the difference between BrowserView and BrowserPage and why do we need two similar classes in zope.publisher? And 2.) Why can I successfully use BrowserPage but not BrowserView?

Comment: My answer above tells why you should use `Five.BrowserView`, not why your example fails. I guess that in the example above you registered a zcml `browser:view` with class `zope.publisher.browser.BrowserPage`. However Zope 2 publisher demands a class that defines `__call__` method.

Comment: In the example you point to, you neither make any security check, neither need to access any other content object through Acquisition. IOW, it does not need a `Five.brower.BrowserView`.